# Changing The Case of A Letter in C?

Tags: c, case, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to change the case of a letter entered by the user and store a lower case and a higher case version of the letter in variables. I've written the code below but it's having issues running. Anyone point out what's causing the problems?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char CaseChange(character){

    int lowerc, higherc;


    if(isupper(character)){
        lowerc = tolower(character);
        printf("%s", lowerc);
    }
    else{
        higherc = character;
        printf("%s", higherc);

    }
    return;
}

int main(void){

    char character;

    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%c", character);

    CaseChange(character);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: In ASCII, you can change the case of a letter by xor-ing it with 0x20.

Comment: What exactly are the issues you are having? Does it not compile (as it shouldn't), is it giving segfaults or strange output (as it should)?

Comment: Sorry, it compiles fine but when I run it it stops working after I enter the character? Like a runtime error

Comment: You should use a better compiler. A smart compiler will warn when the type of the `printf` argument doesn't match the corresponding format specifier.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. And heed them!

Comment: I've never actually heard of a smart compiler, I'm kind of a beginner programmer so I've just been using window'a cmd?

Comment: CaseChange either needs to return a char, or be declared a void function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

1. `printf("%s", ...)` is meant for outputting strings (`char*` and `const char*`), not single characters. Use `printf("%c", ...)`
2. You forgot to `#include <ctype.h>`

Side-note: You don't have to check if a character is uppercase with `isupper(x)`. `tolower(x)` will leave already-lowercase characters intact.

Comment: Third problem: `CaseChange` did not declare the type of `character`

Comment: Fourth problem: The `scanf()` should also use the “address-of” operator on `character`, i.e. `&character`.

Comment: And `CaseChange` didn't return anything (best make the return type `void`), and `scanf` wasn't given the *address* of `character` and had its error code ignored, the `printf` formats don't have a `\n` so if the program runs in a shell that doesn't check the last program it launched finished it's last line of output with a `\n` then it may either wipe out the uppercased character when printing its prompt, or write the prompt mid-line (potentially screwing up the cursor key / scrolling behaviour).

Comment: Thanks guys, this is part of a larger program and I've been making really stupid mistakes that I really should have spotted.

Comment: Actually, @Realt, you should ensure warnings are turned on in your compiler and you should *understand why you get each warning.*